# artillery.io JSON value capture not working

Tags: json, jsonpath

Using Artillery.io 1.6.0-10, I call an api that returns a JSON and try to capture one of the values for later use in the flow, however the capture doesn't seem to be working. Here is the simplified code:

get_ddg.yml

```
config:
  target: "https://api.duckduckgo.com"
  phases:
    - duration: 3
      arrivalCount: 1
scenarios:
  - name: "Get search"
    flow:
      - get:
          url: "/?q=DuckDuckGo&format=json"
          capture:
            json: "$.Abstract"
            as: "abstract"
      - log: "Abstract: {{ $abstract }}"
```

When I run artillery the value is empty:

```
$ artillery run get_ddg.yml
Started phase 0, duration: 3s @ 10:28:34(+0200) 2017-10-25
⠋ Abstract:   <----- EMPTY! NO VALUE FOR $abstract
Report @ 10:28:37(+0200) 2017-10-25
Scenarios launched:  1
Scenarios completed: 1
Requests completed:  1
Concurrent users:    1
RPS sent: 2.08
Request latency:
  min: 311.9
  max: 311.9
  median: 311.9
  p95: NaN
  p99: NaN
Scenario duration:
  min: 349.5
  max: 349.5
  median: 349.5
  p95: NaN
  p99: NaN
Codes:
  200: 1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem is how the variable is read after capture. The correct way to call the variable it is not using the '$':

```
- log: "Abstract: {{ abstract }}"
```